# Caesar Cipher in Python - how to replace characters

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to re-arrange long sentence from a puzzle that is encoded using a Caesar Cipher.

Here is my code.

```
sentence="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

import string

a=string.ascii_lowercase[]
b=a[2:]+a[:2]
for i in range(26):
   sentence.replace(sentence[sentence.find(a[i])],b[i])
```

Am I, missing anything in replace function?
When I tried `sentence.replace(sentence[sentence.find(a[0])],b[0])`

it worked but why I can't loop through?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sentence.replace
```

returns a new string, which you are immediately throwing away. Note that replacing each character repeatedly will cause duplicate replacements in your cipher. See @RemcoGerlich's answer for a better-detailed explanation of what is wrong. As for the solution, what about

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

shifted = {l: letters[(i + 2) % len(letters)] for i, l in enumerate(letters)}    
sentence = ''.join(shifted.get(c, c) for c in sentence.lower())
```

or if you really want the tabled way:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

rotated_lowercase = ascii_lowercase[2:] + ascii_lowercase[:2]
translation_table = str.maketrans(ascii_lowercase, rotated_lowercase)
sentence = sentence.translate(translation_table)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems:

One, `sentence[sentence.find(a[i])]` is strange. It tries to look up where in the sentence the character `a[1]` occurs, and then looks up which character is there. Well, you already know -- `a[1]`. Unless that character doesn't occur in the string, then .find will return -1, and sentence[-1] is the last character in the sentence. Probably not what you meant. So instead you meant `sentence.replace(a[i], b[i])`.

But, you don't save the result anywhere. You meant `sentence = sentence.replace(a[i], b[i])`.

But that still doesn't work! What if `a` should be changed into `b`, and then `b` into `c`? Then the original `a`s are also changed into `c`! That's a fundamental problem with your approach.

Better solutions are given by modesitt. Mine would have been something like

```
lookupdict = {a_char: b_char for (a_char, b_char) in zip(a, b)}
sentence_translated = [lookupdict.get(s, '') for s in sentence]
sentence = ''.join(sentence_translated)
```